# The angular not reseting SELECT when the items is changed

Tags: angular

I have seven columns on a form all are select inputs. When I select a value from the first Select I have to load/refresh the items on the 2nd select. The data comes from the server and I am able to do it also.

The .html is

```
<select 
    id="PouchTypeReference" 
    name="PouchTypeReference" 
    [(ngModel)]="data.CustomerProduct[0].pouch_type_reference" 
    class="form-control"
    (ngModelChange)="onPouchTypeReferenceChange($event)" 
>
    <option value=0>Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let l of lookup.PouchTypeDetails" value={{l.pouch_type_reference}}>{{l.name}}</option>
</select>
{{data.CustomerProduct[0].pouch_type_reference}}
```

And ts code is

```
data: any;
lookup: any;

onPouchTypeReferenceChange(ev) {
    let data = {
        ChangedColumn: 'pouch_type_reference',
        Data: this.data,
        Lookup: this.lookup
    }
    this.http.post<any>(this.apibase + "Product/ItemChanged", data, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + this.authToken)
        }).subscribe(data => {
        if (data) { 
            this.lookup = data.Lookup;          
            this.data = data.Data;
            this.repaintForm(data.FormOptions.Options);
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        if (error.status == 401) {
            localStorage.clear();
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
    }
)
```

The issue now I am facing is the when the line this.lookup = data.Lookup; is excuted, all the select inputs shows "Please select" as the selected value. But the value is not changed, only the display is changed.

[image: Before lookup value is set.]

Please note the selected value displayed on the image. The value is 2. Now after executing the this.lookup = data.Lookup; the select is shown as follows.

[image: Display is changed but the value is still 2]

Please see the value (2) is not changed. only the display is changed to "Please select". This happens on all Select inputs... All of the values are reseted. But the data is accurate when I checked on them.

Can anyone help?